# Redactor image upload set inline style

Tags: css, iframe, redactor

I am using Redactor v10.0.9 to allow users to create some custom posts for my web app. These posts are rendered in an iframe in a modal, and I need images that are uploaded to have a max-width of 100%. I have tried to maintain an outside stylesheet that I append to the iFrame that contains

```
img {
  max-width: 100% !important; } }
```

But that doesn't seem to be working at all. I would like to just add `style="max-width: 100%"` inline style to the img tag when it's inserted, but I can't seem to find where the image is inserted into the post after an image upload.

Any ideas on how to force these images in an iFrame to be `max-width: 100%`? Thanks

**Edit 1:**

I am using the `imagemanager` plugin to upload images to Redactor. Forgot to mention that.

**Edit 2:**

The content contained in the iFrame is dynamically created HTML, not content from another domain.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to do this!

Instead of appending any sort of style to the `img` tag on insertion, when I render the custom posts I am retrieving all of the images in the iFrame in JavaScript, and then applying a CSS attr of `"max-width: 100%"` on each one.